# I'm not signing my RPMs, but they have signatures anyway. "Header V4 RSA/SHA1 signature: BAD"

Tags: macos, homebrew, rpm, rpmbuild, sbt-native-packager

I am building an RPM [using sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/616) on my Mac which can't be installed on RHEL 5 machines because it has a V4 signature. The result of `rpm -v --checksig` on my Mac:

```
Header V4 RSA/SHA1 signature: OK, key ID f769fd38
Header SHA1 digest: OK (2ee9b411052b2aeadcb0efa5401f246af8ca6e68)
MD5 digest: OK (b78e1256caba2959428b1e5544d562a6)
```

And the result of `rpm -v --checksig` on the RHEL 5 machine:

```
Header V4 RSA/SHA1 signature: BAD, key ID f769fd38
Header SHA1 digest: OK (2ee9b411052b2aeadcb0efa5401f246af8ca6e68)
MD5 digest: OK (b78e1256caba2959428b1e5544d562a6)
```

I saw [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52058/40890) which implied that it had to do with GPG signatures, but that doesn't add up.

The sbt-native-packager RPM plugin doesn't do signing according to its developers, as can be evidenced by the `rpmbuild` command it emits:

```
rpmbuild -bb --target noarch-PayPal-Linux --buildroot /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/buildroot --define _topdir /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm --define _tmppath /var/folders/gp/l9gt6r791p1bdcgtf2b2dppw392tbp/T/sbt_8f0f0597 myapp.spec
```

Plus, I don't have `gpg` installed on my Mac, so the fix in the linked answer doesn't really seem to apply to me. I realize that `rpm` usually comes with an installation of `gpg` so maybe it's using that to make the signatures, but I have no idea what key it's using or how to make it force a V3 signature or stop signing entirely. I'm not sure if that last statement was even sensible, as I have very limited experience working with `rpm`.

Nonetheless I did try to at least modify `~/.rpmmacros` as that guide suggested but it was to no avail. I have no leads. Why do my RPMs have signatures if I didn't sign them, and how can I prevent those signatures from being V4?

*Edit* per request, here is the output from sbt (I believe the "error" lines are just an implementation quirk and not actual errors):

```
[debug] Executing rpmbuild with: rpmbuild -bb --target noarch-PayPal-Linux --buildroot /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/buildroot --define _topdir /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm --define _tmppath /var/folders/gp/l9gt6r791p1bdcgtf2b2dppw392tbp/T/sbt_8f0f0597 myapp.spec
[info] Building target platforms: noarch-PayPal-Linux
[info] Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/folders/gp/l9gt6r791p1bdcgtf2b2dppw392tbp/T/sbt_8f0f0597/rpm-tmp.67386
[error] + umask 022
[error] + cd /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/BUILD
[error] + /bin/rm -rf /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/buildroot
[error] + /bin/mkdir -p /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/buildroot
[error] + '[' -e /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/buildroot ']'
[error] + mv /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/tmp-buildroot/etc /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/tmp-buildroot/var /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/tmp-buildroot/x /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/buildroot
[error] + exit 0
[info] Processing files: myapp-VersionNotSet-ReleaseNotSet.noarch
[info] Provides: config(myapp) = 0:VersionNotSet-ReleaseNotSet
[info] Requires(interp): /bin/sh /bin/sh /bin/sh /bin/sh
[info] Requires(pre): /bin/sh
[info] Requires(post): /bin/sh
[info] Requires(preun): /bin/sh
[info] Requires(postun): /bin/sh
[info] Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.15/lib/rpm/check-files /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/buildroot
[info] Wrote: /Users/2rs2ts/src/my-app/my-app/target/rpm/RPMS/noarch/myapp-VersionNotSet-ReleaseNotSet.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: That rpm doesn't actually have anything signed in the header. Those lines are both non-signed data. A signature line would look like `V4 RSA/SHA1 signature: XXX, key ID xxxxxxx` or `V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID xxxxx` or similar. So I'm a bit puzzled as to what is actually being done there. Can you get the full output from the build process and how it handles the rpm after it gets built? Does anything else touch the rpm between the build and where you are looking at it?

Comment: @EtanReisner I can only show you the sbt log (which has all of the debugging info on, and which I have added to my question.) Is there something in particular you're looking for? I can try to find something in the source about it. Unfortunately I know more about this plugin's architecture than about rpms ;)

Comment: I have no idea if this is going to tell us anything but can you run [this python script](https://gist.github.com/deryni/78ee6f01f69a32f3746e) over the rpm in question and either stick the output in a comment on the gist or pastebin it somewhere else? (I'd say put it in the question but I don't know that it will be at all material to the problem ultimately.)

Comment: @EtanReisner I'd love to, but where do I get the `rpm` module? Can't find it on PyPI.

Comment: You already have it. It ships with CentOS/etc. Just run the script, it should work.

Comment: I think I misspoke when I said nothing was signed in that output. I think that might actually be a signed header but no signed payload/data but I'm not sure.

Comment: @EtanReisner I was hoping to get it on my mac :( but okay, I'll do that when I get back to the office, and I'll let you know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, yeah, I don't know if that's built anywhere else. It is part of rpm itself I believe.

Comment: @EtanReisner [Here's the paste](http://pastebin.com/SNG6Nssb). I had to redact some proprietary info so the `RPM_BASENAMES` won't line up with the `RPMTAG_FILEINODES` and other such values but I don't think those were the critical bits of information anyway.

Comment: Something is definitely putting a signature in there. Also a GPG public key. Do you recognize that key? Are you using rpm5 on your mac?

Comment: @EtanReisner I used the `rpm` provided by homebrew (`brew install rpm`) which seems to be version 5.4.15. I do not recognize that public key.

Comment: I'd like to add that the key ID changes every time I run the `rpm:package-bin` task. I wonder if it is a one-off key being created by `rpmbuild`.

Comment: I don't know *anything* about rpm5. It is *ages* newer then the rpm versions I have dealt with on CentOS 5 and CentOS 6. Any number of things may have changed. I would suggest seeing if perhaps there is an rpm 4 version available via brew and seeing if that works more as expected (if nothing else I imagine the resulting rpms are more likely to be compatible with the *much* older rpm on RHEL 5 that way).

Comment: @EtanReisner it seems that there is not a formula for rpm 4. I could go to the trouble of trying to install it but I might just take the path of least resistance and use DSA like Jeff is suggesting.

Comment: If that works for you that is certainly a reasonable idea. I'd thought the issue was trying not to have any signing at all (and not knowing where the current signing was coming from) but *shrug*.

Comment: @EtanReisner That *is* the issue, and until it's resolved I won't mark my question as resolved. But life has to go on nonetheless...

Answer (score 1):

I can hazard a guess: the issue is RSA being broken in several ways in RHEL5 rpm. The easiest fix is to try signing with DSA rather than RSA.

Does DSA "work" on both MAC and RHEL5?

Comment: I use RSA signatures on CentOS 5 at work and they seem to work just fine (assuming you avoid sub-keys, etc.). Are there other problems? As an aside do you know how the OP might have an rpm with a header signature but no payload/data signature (assuming I've interpreted that output correctly)?

Comment: I heard that the problem had to do with 2048-bit keys but I'm not well-versed in the issue, that's just what I saw other questions talking about bad headers talking about... but that was when the RPMs were being explicitly signed.

Comment: @2rs2ts I did a bunch of testing with various keys/etc. on a bunch of different OSes at one point for work (because a coworker made a claim about CentOS 5 not supporting larger RSA keys) and unless my testing was wildly broken I got CentOS 5 rpm to verify an rpm signed with a 4096 bit RSA key.

Comment: Yes some RSA keys "work", others don't, dependent on parameters. An V4 fingerprints are incorrect. I suggest DSA … ymmv.

Comment: Parameters on/of the key itself or sub-keys? (Which gpg makes *extremely* painful to export without.) Feel free to tell me you don't remember/care/etc. anymore. This is hopefully all soon to be ancient history anyway.

Comment: The V4 RSA fingerprint is a hash of the pubkey parameters, rpm not even close to getting it right (V3 RSA fingerprint is different). The other issue is bit count vs byte count: these are identical for DSA which always has the msbit set, but isn't for RSA, which has a chance of 1 in 256 that all 8 bits of  the msbyte of the signature are zero (and rpm gets the length wrong).

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with subkeys, which are entirely unsupported in RPM.

Comment: This will never be ancient history: even after fixing the above flaws, "bugs" appear phenomenologically which even absolutely accurate descriptions of the flaw(s) from the person who did both the implementation and the fixing are unable to correct. ymmv.

Comment: When I set `_build_sign` to DSA it "works". There is still some discrepancy. Mac: `Header V4 DSA signature: OK, key ID 98d3b138` CentOS: `Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 98d3b138`. I'm not sure how to force it to use a V3 signature. I have `--force-v3-sigs` in my `__gpg_sign_cmd`.

Comment: You can force a V3 signature for RSA using ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf (and --force-v3-sigs is likely equivalent). Meanwhile the V3 -> V4 signature format change has been underway all this century. Fixing the RSA fingerprint in RHEL5 rpm isn't impossibly hard either: just RHAT will never release a fix. So using DSA is your least painful solution.

Comment: specific answer: NOKEY just means you should use rpm --import to import the pubkey. Do "rpm -q gpg-pubkey | grep 98d3b138" to verify that the pubkey is imported.

Comment: @JeffJohnson I don't have gpg installed, rpm is using the built-in BeeCrypt (to my understanding.) Adding `--force-v3-sigs` to my `%__gpg_sign_cmd` as was suggested in the tutorial I linked in my OP didn't change anything anyway. I will just end up using DSA probably. It doesn't answer my question but at least it unblocks me. Thanks for all the information!